# How to get id from a loop's item in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a loop like this:

```
<div class="jokes" v-for="joke in jokes">
  <strong>{{joke.body}}</strong>
  <small>{{joke.upvotes}}</small>
  <button v-on:click="upvote"><i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i></button>
<div>
```

I need to get `joke.id` so that I can post it to backend and increment the votes.

The method should be something like this:

```
 methods: {
        upvote: function(e) {
            axios.post( this.BASE_URL + "/api/joke/" + this.joke.id + "/upvote", {
                token: 'secret',
            }).then(function(data){
                console.log(data);
            });
        }
     },
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the `joke` in the click.

```
<button v-on:click="upvote(joke)"><i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i></button>
```

Use it in the method.

```
upvote: function(joke) {
  axios.post( this.BASE_URL + "/api/joke/" + joke.id + "/upvote", {
    token: 'secret',
  }).then(function(data){
    console.log(data);
  });
}
```

Comment: I beat you by two seconds but your answer is more complete :)

Comment: Well, `joke.id` in the method yeilds: `Uncaught ReferenceError: joke is not defined`. And when I trie `this.joke.id` instead, I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`.

Comment: @Karlom Did you remember to change the argument of the function from `function(e)` to `function(joke)`?

Answer (score 2):

In your `v-on:click` event pass the `joke` object: `<button v-on:click="upvote(joke)">`

You may also need to key your loop like so:

```
<div class="jokes" v-for="joke in jokes" :key="joke.id">
```

Answer (score 2):

Value of the `v-on` directive not only can be a handle method name but also an inline statement. So you just need to add an argument for the method like following way.

```
<div class="jokes" v-for="joke in jokes">
  <strong>{{joke.body}}</strong>
  <small>{{joke.upvotes}}</small>
  <button v-on:click="upvote(joke.id)"><i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i></button>
<div>
```

And then the method can get id.

```
methods: {
  upvote: function(id) {
    axios.post(this.BASE_URL + "/api/joke/" + id + "/upvote", {
      token: 'secret',
    }).then(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
},
```

You can learn more form the [API document of Vue](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-on)